# tar (child) : Cannot open: no such File or Directory

Tags: linux, directory, tar

i was trying to install netkit on kali linux with the following standard commands mentioned on netkit.org
commands: Download all the files to a directory of your choice. Then unpack them by using
the following commands:

```
  tar -xjSf netkit-x.y.tar.bz2  
  tar -xjSf netkit-filesystem-Fx.y.tar.bz2  
  tar -xjSf netkit-kernel-Kx.y.tar.bz2
```

**AFter passing the very first command i come up with the error**

**code :**

```
 root@kali:/home# tar -xjSf netkit-2.8.tar.bz2
```

**error:**

```
  tar (child): netkit-2.8.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
     tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
     tar: Child returned status 2
     tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

can anybody please explain what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The file isn't there. You've mistyped its name, or you're in the wrong directory.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes i was in the wrong directory , not actually a wrong directory was in different user so it was not able to unpack , got it done now thx for your support

Comment: Those who downvoted this question and marked it as duplicate for Kali Linux, how one supposed to know the question to `tar` can be found in a question regarding Linux distribution? Even if the answer is there, I still don't think these two are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of this prompt:

```
root@kali:/home# tar -xjSf netkit-2.8.tar.bz2
```

You're not in the directory where the .tar.bz2 file is located. Confirm that the file is in this location. You likely need to `cd ~` to get back to your `/home/kali` directory which is probably where your netkit-2.8.tar.bz2` file is located.

If you've resolved this issue, then the next would be the filename you're using:

```
root@kali:/home/slimshady/netkit2# ls netkit-filesystem-i386-F5.2.tar.bz2
```

Based on this, notice the file name, so the `tar` command should be:

```
$ tar jxSf netkit-filesystem-i386-F5.2.tar.bz2
```

Comment: I tried doing that , was still unable to unpack the file.  Also tried making a new directory named my netkit itself and moved the files there still the same error occured

Comment: Please show the output of `ls` where you're running the `tar` command.

Comment: root@kali:/home/slimshady/netkit2# ls                                                               
netkit-filesystem-i386-F5.2.tar.bz2

Comment: @jasrajsandhu - look at the name of the file - `tar -xjSf netkit-filesystem-i386-F5.2.tar.bz2 `.

Comment: the first file i somehow managed to install this is the second now im trying and the same scenario appearing

Comment: got it done thx for your help

Comment: I have the same error with `gz` file. The file name is ok, and `ls` shows it in the current directory and I was able to unzip it with `alpine` image but since I switched to amazonlinux it doesn't work any more: `tar -zxvf helmfile.tar.gz`

Comment: @xbmono - keep in mind that different distros have different implementations of `tar` typically, so that might be the case w/ your particular situation.